# C++ date validation runs continuous

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes user input, and then verifies that it is an actual date. The program runs fine and does what I want it to, but I am trying to clean up the output. If a user types `two` for example instead of `02` for the month, the program catches the error, but the next two `cout` statements are still executed (without the chance for input) and then the error message is displayed to the user.

Here is the code:

```
void getInput(int& month, int& day, int& year)
{
    //prompt the user for the date
    cout << "***************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the Date Validator Program created by ****!" << endl;
    cout << "***************************************************************" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter your date below. Use only whole, positive numbers." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the month in MM format: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Please enter the day of the month in DD format: ";
    cin >> day;
    cout << "Please enter the year in YYYY formating: ";
    cin >> year;

    //send input to boolean validation function to verify valid date
        isValidDate(month, day, year);
        while (!isValidDate(month, day, year))
        {
            cin.sync();
            cin.clear();
            cout << "\nSorry, the date you have entered is invalid!" << endl <<
                "Hint: Make sure you are using only positive, whole integers for input." << endl <<
                "Please try again!" << endl << endl;

            cout << "Please enter the month in MM format using numbers: ";
            cin >> month;
            cout << "Please enter the day of the month in DD format using numbers: ";
            cin >> day;
            cout << "Please enter the year in YYYY formating using numbers: ";
            cin >> year;
        }
    }

    bool isValidDate(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        if (!(1 <= month && month <= 12) || (!cin))
            return false;
        if (!(1 <= day && day <= 31) || (!cin))
                return false;
            if ((day == 31) && (month == 2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) || (!cin))
                return false;
            if ((day == 30) && (month == 2) || (!cin))
                return false;
            if ((month == 2) && (day == 29) && (year % 4 != 0) || (!cin))
                return false;
            if ((month == 2) && (day == 29) && (year % 400 == 0) && (cin))
                return true;
            if ((month == 2) && (day == 29) && (year % 100 == 0) || (!cin))
                return false;
            if ((month == 2) && (day == 29) && (year % 4 == 0) && (cin))
                return true;
            if ((month == 2) && (day > 29) || (!cin))
                return false;
            return true;
    }
```

How do I get it not to display the `cout` for the day and year if input is wrongly entered at the month output?

I am also having an issue ensuring the year is in `YYYY` format. Any help on what I am missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: But where? Am I doing it in the wrong place? Would it be better to validate `cin` before I send it to the vaildation method?

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// Set the failbit on the stream if the stream or value is invalid
// Note: Additional input is silently ignored.
std::istream& isValid(std::istream& stream, int value) {
    // The current stream state.
    bool success = bool(stream);
    // Clear a possible fail state, but not EOF.
    // Note: This example fails miserable, if the I/O is not interactive.
    //       Input through a pipeline or similar needs additional coding.  
    stream.clear(stream.eof() ? stream.eofbit : stream.goodbit);
    // Ignore the rest of the line.
    stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    // Validate the number
    if(success) {
        // Only one valid value
        if(value != 1)
            success = false;
    }
    // Adjust the stream state.
    if( ! success)
        stream.setstate(stream.failbit);
    return stream;
}

void getInput(int& result)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number ";
    std::cin >> result;

    while( ! isValid(std::cin, result)) {
        std::cout << "Sorry, Please enter a number again " ;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> result;
    }
}

int main() {
    int result;
    getInput(result);
    std::cout << "Result " << result << '\n';
}
```

The code evaluates the stream state, first. Then, it validates the input and adjusts the stream state, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate every cin alone and then validate the whole thing i.e :

```
for (;;) {
    cout << "Please enter the month in MM format using numbers: ";
    if (cin >> taxableIncome) {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter the month in MM format using numbers: " << endl;
        cin.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> If a user types two for example instead of `02` for the month, the program catches the error, but the next two `cout` statements are still executed (without the chance for input) and then the error message is displayed to the user.

The problem is that `cin` if raising a `fail()`(error state flag) if it detects wrong type input in one of your three lines containing `cin`, and then this causes the rest of the input to fail as well. This is why nothing is displaying as a value in the rest, if only one fails.

### The simplest change would be: (a loop till everything is right)

```
void getInput(int& month, int& day, int& year){
//prompt the user for the date
cout << "***************************************************************" << endl;
cout << "Welcome to the Date Validator Program created by ****!" << endl;
cout << "***************************************************************" << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter your date below. Use only whole, positive numbers." << endl;

do{
    // get input
    cout << "Please enter the month in MM format: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Please enter the day of the month in DD format: ";
    cin >> day;
    cout << "Please enter the year in YYYY formating: ";
    cin >> year;
    isValidDate(month, day, year);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    //send input to be validated    
   }while (!isValidDate(month, day, year))
}
```

As for:

> I am also having an issue ensuring the year is in YYYY format. Any help on what I am missing?

Just specify what you consider a valid interval for a year, for example YYYY:[2000,2015], and add it to you validation function:

```
 bool isValidDate(int month, int day, int year)
{ 
    if (year < 2000 && year > 2015) return false;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Enter a 'Z' and it loops infinite